# Any good (really good) material on Poco C++?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

Hardly can I find any good material on Poco C++. Their documentation cannot replace a good 3rd party tutorial enriched with real-world examples and lit with creativity. Please refer some if you know any. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have now posted lots of introductory slides to our documentation website: http://pocoproject.org/documentation